# libxml2 use in android

Tags: android, xml, android-ndk, libxml2

I have successfully cross compiled a C++ library for Android, this library uses libxml2. Now when i try to test it through my jni layer, the native calls seems work fine. But when I do a basic call which imply to parse an xml file(from an url), a libxml function fails.

The `xmlTextReaderPtr xmlReaderForFile(const char* filename, const char* encoding, int options)` fonction returns `NULL`.

I call it with an http url, so I wonder if it could be a network access problem.

I've added the internet permission in the manifest but without result.

The error occurs as soon the `xmlTextReaderPtr xmlNewTextReaderFilename(const char* URI)` is called in the libxml library and `errno` is set to "No such file or directory". Note the url I use works fine with the "same" CPP code on ubuntu.

I hope somebody can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libxml2 on Android is [compiled without HTTP support](https://github.com/android/platform_external_libxml2/blob/master/include/libxml/xmlversion.h#L172).